# Removing duplicate multiply rows from CSV file using a awk

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, duplicates, unique

i've used this code to remove duplicates in column #3 from 2 files

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{seen[$3]; next} !($3 in seen)' dublicates.txt need_check.csv > output.csv
```

But how to check for duplicates if i want check multiply columns (#2,#3 and #4)?

Comment: What is the logic of `duplicates` with multiple columns? In case any of the three columns are the same across rows, or all of them are the same? It will be helpful if you can illustrate with an actual sample file.

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to an ambiguity in your question, there are two possible answers.

If you consider as duplicates records that have the same fields #2, #3 AND #4, you should run:

```
awk -F, '{key=$2 FS $3 FS $4} NR==FNR{a[key]; next} !(key in a) dublicates.txt need_check.csv > output.csv
```

If records are duplicates when only one of the fields is repeated, then you have to code it in another way.

It is a good practice at SO to include a sample of input and the desired corresponding output.

Comment: @EdMorton: thank you for editing my answer. I agree with all the changes. I miss also a sample of input files to test the software.